# How to find comments that I react "Like" on github

Tags: github

There are some issues in a repository on github. There are some comments there. I react 'Like/heart/... as a quick note. 
Is it possible to find the comments that I reacted? I need to find them later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides the reaction, if the issue is important to you, you should also subscribe to the issue:
[image]

that way you receive notifications in the progress,
and you can see all the issues you are subscribed to in the page:
https://github.com/notifications?all=1

Comment: I think this is the proper link to see all subscriptions. The above link shows recent activity only. https://github.com/notifications/subscriptions

Answer (score 8):

Searching for reactions on github.com does not appear to be supported at the moment:

- https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/#search-by-commenter
- https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/

You can find a discussion about the need for this feature in an unofficial community github issue tracker here:

- https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1216
- https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/607

You can send a request for this feature to: https://github.com/contact

You can also send an email with a feature request to: support@github.com